# How do I create a class instance from a string name in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I want the Crystal equivalent of this:

```
clazz = 'ExampleClass'.constantize # Rails
clazz = Object.const_get('ExampleClass') # pure Ruby
obj = clazz.new
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, these kind of dynamic aspects are not possible in Crystal.

However, macros can take a long way. Please read this similar issue and discussion:

https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/949